# NodeJS require's body sometimes is object and sometimes string?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, require

In this function:

```
exports.subscribeWebhook = function (page, pageToken) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request({
            url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/subscribed_apps',
            qs: {
                access_token: pageToken //Query string: ?access_token=pageToken
            },
            method: 'GET'
        }, function (error, response, body) {
```

when I try to parse the body with `JSON.parse(body)` I get no problems, but for this one, which is a `POST`:

```
exports.call = function (method, botId, json) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({
            url: 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'+mongo.mongoCache.telegramPageTokens[botId]+"/"+method,
            method: 'POST',
            json: json//remember to don't even set the json property if it's undefined (or maybe it's default?)
        }, function (error, response, body) {
```

when I try to parse the body, I get an error. When I print the body, it's just a JSON object, no other things, but if I do `typeof(body)` I get `Object`, but for the first function, I get `string`.

I know I could just stringfy and then parse but I want to understand what's happening. Why sometimes the body is a string and sometimes it's an object?

Answer (score 1):

setting `json` property to true sets application/json header for the request and additionally parses response as JSON (so you dont have to)

read about it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

the first request to facebooks returns string encoded response that is why you need to parse it yourself

Comment: If I set json:true then the returned object will already be a json, right?

Comment: yes, that is what documentation say in description for this property. you can always do a check for a string before you do JSON.parse to make your callback function usable in both cases

Comment: but shouldn't the json option be used to send json documents? Or the fact that I'm sending a document already sets it to true?

Comment: where did you find this json:true thing? I can find only examples in this page